# Symfony on Xampp (Apache) issue: The page is not loading

Tags: apache, symfony, xampp, localhost

My Apache local server is running on XAMPP. I created new symfony project and had issues right from the start. The page was not loading. Then I installed .htaccess using this command:

```
composer require symfony/apache-pack
```

and it still didn't work. Then about an hour later it started working by itself. (I am not sure if I even refreshed the page).

Anyway, after some manual changes with controller, the page stopped loading again.

It says:

> This site can't be reached
>
> The connection was reset.
>
> ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

[image]

I really have no idea what may cause this problem.

Apache is running, other projects (not Symfony) are running ok as well. Only this symfony project is problematic.

I think I have everything set up right:

httpd-vhost file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/myproject/public"
    ServerName myproject
</VirtualHost>
```

hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1   myproject
```

.htaccess file (created by `composer require symfony/apache-pack` command):

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$0 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
    RewriteRule .* - [E=BASE:%1]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .+
    RewriteRule ^ - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%0]

    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} =""
    RewriteRule ^index\.php(?:/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$1 [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ %{ENV:BASE}/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_alias.c>
        RedirectMatch 307 ^/$ /index.php/
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

So I really have no idea how to work this out. I tried clearing the cache in my web browser but it did not help.

EDIT: It works when I change index.php and instead of symfony code:

```
<?php

use App\Kernel;

require_once dirname(__DIR__).'/vendor/autoload_runtime.php';

return function (array $context) {
    return new Kernel($context['APP_ENV'], (bool) $context['APP_DEBUG']);
};
```

I tried to use:

```
<?php
echo "Hello World!";
```

It echoes

> Hello World

with any problem.

EDIT 2: It seems the problem is with routing. When I create MainController.php (as a new file) it stops working. When I delete the whole file, it starts working again. Deleting the contents of the file won't do it, I really need to delete the actual file to make it work again. Weird.

EDIT 3:
Here is some contents of my dev.log file:

```
[2021-11-07T20:21:04.744060+01:00] php.DEBUG: Warning: DOMDocument::schemaValidateSource(): Invalid Schema {"exception":{"Symfony\\Component\\ErrorHandler\\Exception\\SilencedErrorContext":{"severity":2,"file":"C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\myproject_cz\\vendor\\symfony\\translation\\Util\\XliffUtils.php","line":113,"trace":[{"file":"C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\myproject_cz\\vendor\\symfony\\translation\\Util\\XliffUtils.php","line":64,"function":"shouldEnableEntityLoader","class":"Symfony\\Component\\Translation\\Util\\XliffUtils","type":"::"}],"count":1}}} []

[2021-11-07T20:39:31.249487+01:00] request.ERROR: Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: "No route found for "GET http://myproject_cz/"" at C:\xampp\htdocs\myproject_cz\vendor\symfony\http-kernel\EventListener\RouterListener.php line 136 {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\NotFoundHttpException(code: 0): No route found for \"GET http://myproject_cz/\" at C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\myproject_cz\\vendor\\symfony\\http-kernel\\EventListener\\RouterListener.php:136)\n[previous exception] [object] (Symfony\\Component\\Routing\\Exception\\NoConfigurationException(code: 0):  at C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\myproject_cz\\vendor\\symfony\\routing\\Matcher\\Dumper\\CompiledUrlMatcherTrait.php:182)"} []

[2021-11-07T20:39:31.518751+01:00] request.INFO: Matched route "_wdt". {"route":"_wdt","route_parameters":{"_route":"_wdt","_controller":"web_profiler.controller.profiler::toolbarAction","token":"61c0ae"},"request_uri":"http://myproject_cz/_wdt/61c0ae","method":"GET"} []
```

I guess the request.ERROR would be the one that causes the problem.

EDIT 4: All the log reports above are generating from refreshing the default symfony page when no Controller was created yet. So they are all IRRELEVANT.

When I create a new controller (either by copying LuckyController example from Symfony Documentation or by using command: `$ php bin/console make:controller MainController`) no more logs are generated and the page simply stops loading. It actually seems to be loading for a few seconds after each refresh but then it ends up unloaded with ERR_CONNECTION_RESET page.

Comment: Have you checked whether Apache is really running? Does it serve static files?

Comment: Of course, I checked. It is running and other projects (running on Apache) are working ok.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Your question does not contain any code from that `MainController` class. Have you tried using a higher error reporting level, or setting your application to a debug environment?

Comment: It does not work with any code in MainController.php. I even tried LuckyController from the documentation: https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller.html and it does not work. Only deleteting the whole file (MainController.php) makes Symfony work again and show the deafult Symfony page.

Comment: I don't know how to set higher error reporting level or debug environment (I am using DEV environment). And I don't even think it will help since the page does not load whatsoever so I have no access to profiler.

Comment: I tried to reinstall the Symfony project but the problem remains.

Comment: What have you tried to check **why** the page is not loading? Is anything written to the log files, either of Symfony or of the webserver?

Comment: I added the contents of dev.log file, see EDIT 3.

Comment: And what have you tried to resolve the problem? Now that you are seeing the errors, what keeps you from fixing them?

Comment: The reason is that I don't know how to fix them.

Comment: `No route found for "GET http://myproject_cz/"` sounds pretty clear to me: there is no route defined that matches the request. As you haven't shared any controller or routing configuration, it's impossible to tell you where this is going wrong

Comment: I shared: LuckyController   (see symfony.com/doc/current/controller.html)

Comment: I am pretty sure the problem is not in the MainController.php file, otherwise it would be handled by Profiler. It seems that the .htaccess file is not set correctly or there is some other issue in Symfony.

Comment: Btw. those log reports are from yesterday where I may have some errors in the routing (nevertheless it still showed "This site can't be reached" page). No new log reports are generated when I refresh the page now, so I guess the problem is really somewhere else. Maybe firewall is blocking it somehow or something like that.

Comment: @NicoHaase I am afraid, you did not get it right. It is NOT problem with a bad routing in controller but there is some other isuue that prevents the page from loading.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was not able to load the Example in the docs as well and when i used the composer serve:start it was working but when i ran using xampp it was not working.

I resolved the issue by creating a new file `.htaccess` in the public directory of the project.

and this is the code that i added which will redirect everything to the `index.php` file:
this is what the file looks like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}/index.php [L]
```